# Density estimation for time series data

Tags: time-series, density-estimation

Suppose I have a collection of time series for a number of subjects, say $y_{ij}$ are measurements for subject $i$ at time $t_{ij}$.  The times are not uniformly sampled and each subject may have a different number of measurements.

I'm interested in ways to estimate the time-varying probability density on $y$, call it $p(y,t)$.  Are there are relatively straightforward ways to estimate this from my scattered data?  Would consider both parametric and nonparametric methods (time dependent KDE...?).  Can I get a density from a mixed effects model on the data (NLME) or is that heading down the wrong path?

Images below give an example.  The scatter plot has a LOWESS line to show the average over time.  The second plot shows the individual time series for each subject ($N\approx 1200$)

[image]
[image]